# Is there any way to compare two array's key to each other, and if those keys are equal, assign the values of the first array to the classes objects?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. The first one contains an id, username, and password from the database and it looks something like this:

```
Array ( [id] => 3 [username] => Scott [password] => new )
```

The second array is

```
get_class_vars();
```

and obviously contains all of the classes vars which are id, username, etc..

How can I go about comparing the keys from both arrays and then if the keys are the same, for example username=username, how can I assign the values of username to the class property username? it's worth noting that I've already instantiated the class and am calling the methods from test.php:

```
// authenticate returns user info from the db 
$user = new User();
$find = $user->authenticate($username, $password);
$user->instantiate($find) // this is the method that I need to create
                          // in user.php to assign the user properties
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I been trying to come up with a solution for hours. If you need any clarification please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$common_keys = array_intersect(array_keys($array), array_keys(get_class_vars($object));
foreach($common_keys as $key) $object->$key = $array[$key];
```

Comment: This looks like a winner. It this method were inside the class, for the get class vars parameter, would I just substitute $object with $this?

Comment: Not quite. `get_object_vars($this)` will allow access to protected and private variables as well (due to the scope in which you use $this). I would suggest keeping a data array and using getter/setters instead. See PHP's magic method docs for more info. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach(get_class_vars() as $key->$value)
  $array[$key] = $value;
```

This gets the key from `get_class_vars()` and sets that value in `$array` (your other array) to `$value`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports storing variable and function names in other variables. Using that, you could iterate over all keys of your array, check if the key exists as an attribute of your `User` object, and if so, replace the value in the object with the one from your array:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($user->$key)) {
        $user->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

So for `Array ( [username] => JohnSmith )` it will check `isset($user->username)` and then assign `$user->username = 'JohnSmith'`.